# How to modify only one element in a react .map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm a little new to react and was a little lost with what to do here. I'm loading data from firebase and rendering the props of that object using a .map function to list all the 'comments' on a page, which works fine. I also want to call a component that would allow the user to reply an individual comment (i.e. one specific element in the map), but as expected by this code, when the reply button is clicked it displays the called component under every element of the map, which isn't desirable. Is there anyway I could call the component for just one element of the map in this case?

```
changeIsReply() {
  this.setState(
    {isReply: !this.state.isReply,}
  );
}    

  render() {

  return (
    <div>
    <ul className="list-group">
    {Object.values(this.props.commentInfo).map((data) =>
      data.map((secondData, i) =>
        <div className="commentHolder" key={i}>
            <p>{secondData.text}</p>
            <p>{secondData.category}</p>
            <p>{secondData.organization}</p>
            <button> UpButton </button> <br />
            <button> DownButton </button>
            <button onClick = {this.changeIsReply} > Reply </button>
            {this.state.isReply ? <SetComment id={secondData.key} /> : null}
        </div>
      )
    )}
    </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you are using a single state for all the comments.

```
<button onClick = {() => this.changeIsReply(secondData.key)} > Reply </button>

{this.state.isReply && this.state.clickedComment == {secondData.key} ? <SetComment id={secondData.key} /> : null}
```

and change your `changeIsReply()` to:

```
changeIsReply(clickedId) {
    this.setState({
        isReply: !this.state.isReply, 
        clickedComment: clickedId
    });
}
```

See if this works. Don't forget to add the new state to your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of which comment should have SetComment component instead.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    // init commentReplyIds as empty array
    commentReplyIds : [],
    // ... rest of your state
  }
}

changeIsReply(commentId) {
  const newCommentReplyIds = [...this.state.commentReplyIds. commentId];
  this.setState(
    {commentReplyIds: newCommentReplyIds}
  );
}    

  render() {
  // in here I am using the data.text as the unique id of each comment, you can use other serializable value.
  return (
    <div>
    <ul className="list-group">
    {Object.values(this.props.commentInfo).map((data) =>
      data.map((secondData, i) =>
        <div className="commentHolder" key={i}>
            <p>{secondData.text}</p>
            <p>{secondData.category}</p>
            <p>{secondData.organization}</p>
            <button> UpButton </button> <br />
            <button> DownButton </button>
            <button onClick = {() => this.changeIsReply(secondData.text)} > Reply </button>
            {this.state.commentReplyIds.includes(secondData.text) ? <SetComment id={secondData.key} /> : null}
        </div>
      )
    )}
    </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

With this approach, you can have multiple `SetComment` components, in different comments of which the user has clicked the reply comment button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep `isReply` to be an array of array and based on index of the comment clicked, update only the proper value, something like

```
state= {
   isReply: [[]]
}
changeIsReply(i, j) {
  var isReply = [...this.state.isReply]
  if(isReply[i] === undefined) {
    isReply.push([true]) = 
  } else {
    if(isReply[i][j] === undefined) {
      isReply[i].push(true)
    } else {
       isReply[i][j] = !isReply[i][j]
    }
  }
  this.setState(
    {isReply}
  );
}    

  render() {

  return (
    <div>
    <ul className="list-group">
    {Object.values(this.props.commentInfo).map((data, i) =>
      data.map((secondData, j) =>
        <div className="commentHolder" key={j}>
            <p>{secondData.text}</p>
            <p>{secondData.category}</p>
            <p>{secondData.organization}</p>
            <button> UpButton </button> <br />
            <button> DownButton </button>
            <button onClick = {() => this.changeIsReply(i, j)} > Reply </button>
            {this.state.isReply[i][j] ? <SetComment id={secondData.key} /> : null}
        </div>
      )
    )}
    </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest breaking this into two components. The `CommentList` and the `Comment` component.

**comment-list.js**

```
import Comment from './comment';

class CommentList extends Component{
    render(){
    return(
        <div>
        <ul className="list-group">
                {Object.values(this.props.commentInfo).map((data) =>
                data.map((secondData, i) =>
                    <Comment text={secondData.text} category={secondData.category} organization={secondData.organization} key={secondData.key} />
      )
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**comment.js**

```
class Comment extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isReply: false
    }
  }
  changeIsReply = () => {
    this.setState(
      {isReply: !this.state.isReply,}
    );
  }   
    render(){
    const {text, category, organization, key} = this.props;
    return(
      <div className="commentHolder" key={i}>
        <p>{text}</p>
        <p>{category}</p>
        <p>{organization}</p>
        <button> UpButton </button> <br />
        <button> DownButton </button>
        <button onClick = {this.changeIsReply} > Reply </button>
        {this.state.isReply ? <SetComment id={key} /> : null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Comment;
```

This way each comment has control over its own state and whether or not to show the `SetComment` component. 
Try to make more components instead of putting all markup in a single render method. This also helps organize your code so that you are mapping each set of values to *a component* which I feel makes it a little easier to wrap your head around.