# How to select only one element of a .map()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `.map()` function which returns these buttons I would like to render according to the number of products pulled from woocommerce api. 
I also have an onclick function in which when one button should only be selected and in turn the `className` toggles.

However, with the script I have all the elements of the array get selected. I am familiar I have to pass my unique `key={}` to the functions to get my desired result but I am having trouble doing so :/  Here is my code with out my attempts https://codesandbox.io/s/018488478p .

I have had a look at these previous questions:
[How to toggle class for the only one element on click in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289315/how-to-toggle-class-for-the-only-one-element-on-click-in-react)
[How to modify only one element in a react .map function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427203/how-to-modify-only-one-element-in-a-react-map-function)
but I cannot replicate it to my code for some reason - I am pretty new to this all so forgive my ignorance if its an easy fix!

Also how come my div expands when the toggle happens its very annoying? :( 
Do you think its better I use radio buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cases like this I like keep track of selected elements in the state like so:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/rm8n26po1q

UPDATE:
I Updated the sandbox, to not include the id, plus a few other improments

Comment: this is awesome @Filtenborg ! exactly what I wanted. One question thou, why have you also passed `id` in the function as so: `handleSelectL1(id, i)` . I'm still learning about all this. I understand you're passing two parameters but why also `id`?

Comment: Oh you don't need that, you can just remove that, and remember to remove it from your handleSelects as well

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to read id of the product, but you never set its id. Add id property to each of your product

Comment: thanks @yewhral ! But I'm not entirely sure on how to do this hence the questions could you show me an example please

Answer (score 0):

In your state you're setting showL1 to true or false, meaning they will all get the style.  In your handleSelectL1 you should set a key in state called "selectedItemId" or similar and set that as the id you are passing in. Then in className you can use `className={this.state.selectedItemId === p.id ? "selectedRBox" : "selectorRBox"`

Comment: Hi thanks @lysdexic for your response! Erm but I'm a little confused. So am I adding this to the constructor `selectedItemId : " ",`  and then simply calling this as you've stated in your response. How do I add `selectedItemId` to `handleSelectL1`? I'm not greatly familiar with this area as I am still learning.

Comment: you pass in the id in the method so just use `this.setState({ selectedItemId: id })`